CORS Error with Next.js and AWS API Gateway Setup
I'm dealing with some CORS problems in a web project where I'm using Next.js hosted via the SST framework (using AWS API Gateway with Lambda).
Im receiving an error in my front end when fetching from the api.dev.domain.com domain while at the origin dev.domain.com. I'm receiving a CORS error; why?
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy

I have configured our API Gateway to accept all HTTP methods, all headers, and all origins.
I have attempted to send the Authorization header using the lambda functions as well as the front end. In the CORS settings, I have also specifically set the headers, origins, and exposed headers. There doesn't seem to be a solution.
Here is my code.
import { Api as ApiGateway, Function, use } from 'sst/constructs';
import { StackContext } from 'sst/constructs/FunctionalStack';

export function Api({ stack }: StackContext) {
const api = new ApiGateway(stack, 'Api', {
cors: {
allowOrigins: ['*'],
allowHeaders: ['Authorization'],
allowMethods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
exposeHeaders: ['Authorization', 'Content-Length'],
},
routes: {
'POST /helper/login': new Function(stack, 'login', {
runtime: 'nodejs18.x',
handler: 'src/packages/functions/helper/login.handler',
}),
'POST /helper/sign-up': {
function: new Function(stack, 'sign-up', {
runtime: 'nodejs18.x',
handler: 'src/packages/functions/helper/sign-up.handler',
}),
payloadFormatVersion: '2.0',
},
},
customDomain: {
domainName: 'api.dev.domain.com',
hostedZone: 'dev.domain.com',
},
});

stack.addOutputs({
ApiEndpoint: api.url,
});

return api;
}

Any help would be much appreciated!.
